# Keras installation

Tags: python, installation, keras

I create an virtual environment in my conda named 'keras_ev' and install the keras in it 
by

```
conda install keras
```

after that when i

```
activate keras_ev
jupyter notebook
```

the notebook does not show my keras_ev environment [image]

and i fail to import the keras in my notebook.

Does anybody know how to fix this! Thank you

Comment: Try the "conda env" one. And run `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)`. If you see that the printed file is in the folder with the name of your environment, it's ok.

Comment: the command window shows "'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. " Is there any other way?

Comment: This should be run inside the jupyter notebook, this will show which python version the notebook chose to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `conda install ipykernel` in your `keras_ev` environment. Then it should appear in your Jupyter notebook.

You can also install Python dependencies while using your Jupyter notebook. First, activate the environment `keras_ev` in another terminal tab. Then install your dependency using conda or pip (conda is recommended). It should be something like the text below.

In a new terminal:

```
source activate keras_ev
conda install *your_package*
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for Keras to work you should first install one of its backends. If you don't install any of the backends it won't work, although it seems that it is installed. please refer to [here](https://keras.io/#installation).

Answer (score 0):

If you have anaconda navigator installed, you can manually go there and click the environments panel (make sure to go to your preferred environment, there is a button in which you can select this)and add Keras. Then, if you run any application off of anaconda, it will automatically have Keras.

Answer (score 0):

- First You need to install Anaconda in your computer. Make sure, you
  need to install anaconda for your python version.
- After install that setup the anaconda environment and you need to
  create new environment using anaconda prompt or command prompt or
  terminal

  conda create -n yourEnvName python=3.6

Now you can activate your environment using follwing command

```
activate yourEnvName
```

Now install keras using PIP. Before install keras you need to install tensorflow because keras run top of the tensorflow

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for activate the enviroment:

```
conda activate keras_ev
```

now, try to start the jupyter notebook using

```
jupyter notebook
```

or

```
jupyter lab
```